# Добавление Yandex Mapkit на Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, yandexmapkit

Пытаюсь добавить Mapkit в активити. На сайте (https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-quickstart/concepts/android/quickstart.html) шаг 3.2 и 3.3. код изначально указан на Java, а у меня проект на Kotlin. Вставив код в HomeActivity.kt на java android studio переконвертировало его в kotlin, но после постройки Apk активити не открывается и приложение вылетает. В чем может быть ошибка? Ниже прикрепляю исходный код с сайта и тот что в проекте. Помогите пожалуйста переконвентировать.

Исходный код:

```
private MapView mapview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapKitFactory.setApiKey("Ваш API-ключ");
    MapKitFactory.initialize(this);

    // Укажите имя Activity вместо map.
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    mapview = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapview.getMap().move(
        new CameraPosition(new Point(55.751574, 37.573856), 11.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0),
        null);
}
```

Конверт в котлин:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.yandex.mapkit.Animation
import com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory
import com.yandex.mapkit.geometry.Point
import com.yandex.mapkit.map.CameraPosition
import com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView



class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mapview: MapView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        MapKitFactory.setApiKey("1679252a-bd27-4314-9146-6634f6461607")


        // Укажите имя Activity вместо map.
        mapview = findViewById(R.id.mapview)
        mapview?.map!!.move(
            CameraPosition(Point(55.751574, 37.573856), 11.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0F),
            null
        )

        supportActionBar?.hide()
    }
}
```

P.S.

Логи чистые, ошибок или предупреждений не выдает. API ключ введен верно, в тело activity, и не требуется до подключения библиотеки.
[image: Event Log]

Comment: Можно долго гадать. С вероятностью в 99% вы сразу поймёте что не так если посмотрите логи. Без логов можно только безосновательно (почти) тыкать пальцем в небо - у вас в оригинале картам даётся ключ и они инициализируются до установки разметки в которой, наверное, есть MapView, который требует ключа у карт и их инициализации до начала отображения

Comment: логи приложения надо смотреть в logcat, а event log - это логи IDE

Answer (score 0):

ссылка на исходный код https://github.com/Samarynin/YandexMapkitTest

Здесь тоже код на java, android studio переконвертировало его в kotlin, но тоже есть ошибки, не могу исправить. Проект на java полностью рабочий.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в котлин ключ желательно получать до setContentView и уж точно проинициализировать карту в методе onCreate до setContentView. Пример:

```
MapKitFactory.setApiKey("1679252a-bd27-4314-9146-6634f6461607")
 MapKitFactory.initialize(context:)
 setContentView()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MapKitFactory.setApiKey("key")
MapKitFactory.initialize(context)
```

А так же нужно добавить override методы

```
override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop()
    }

override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart()
    }
```